# Saving to local storage on Mobile devices [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple note taking app that saves to local storage. Built with React. It works fine on desktop.

However if I go on the site on mobile it doesn't save to local storage. Is there something I need to know for this.

Code looks like this

```
export default function App() {
  const localNotes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(localNotes);

  const handleChange = e => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", e.target.value);
    setNotes(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label for="pad">
        <span>Add your notes</span>
        <textarea
          rows="10"
          placeholder="Add notes here "
          name="pad"
          value={notes}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: what mobile have you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to write on a device you need to have access, the function that you using to save run perfectly on Desktop but its a whole other away to do so, on Devices, Android or iOS. You should look at that up.